# Does Ruby on Rails have a way to import an existing database schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I know I can do a db:create and create database tables or db:migrate to a new version, however what I want to do is import the schema from an existing database (all tables) and generate models for each one.

Does ActiveRecord have the ability to do this?

Comment: It isn't hard to generate models by hand for existing/legacy tables. Start with a simple model and get the tablename, primary key and fieldnames created. Run Rail's console and generate a find command for the first record. You'll see the SQL generated which will give you what you need to fine tune the model. Most legacy table field naming will run afoul ActiveRecord's assumptions so you'll have to correct it. I had to tie together several databases doing this and it went pretty fast once I got the hang of it. Don't use migrations though - your DBA will hate you if one goes rogue.

Comment: Except DO use migrations.  Database configuration is part of the deployment process and you should be using migrations with your deployments to make sure your database matches your application.  DBAs should be involved in the design of your tables, but not the deployment of your schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  ActiveRecord is an ORM, so it doesn't have anything to do with generating database schemas or generating models.  Rails doesn't have any concept of doing this, either.

You'll have to write the database migrations and do this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There's kind of a way. Create a new Rails **2.2** app (it can't be 2.3 or 3.0, the gem hasn't been updated since 2007). Then install and use the [Magic Model Generator](http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_model_generator/) gem.

This will look at your existing database and extra all the models from it, like magic. Since the structure of basic ActiveRecord model files is pretty similar in Rails 3, you can just copy them into your current project and tweak as necessary.